# iText 7 HTML to PDF conversion

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I am using iText 7 for PDF generation.I need to append Rich Text which having HTML document. In itext 5, i was using Chunk class for extracting data. But in itext 7 I don't see any API.

And I tried with the code

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(is, os, properties);
```

But it is giving below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.itextpdf.layout.font.FontSet.getFonts()Ljava/util/Set;
at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.processDocument(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:107)
at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.Attacher.attach(Attacher.java:18)
at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(HtmlConverter.java:108)
at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:85)
at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:81)
at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:69)
at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:65)
```

Comment: This kind of error is typical of some mismatched version in dependencies

Comment: What are the exact versions of iText 7 and pdfHtml that you are using?

Comment: itext 7 i am using 7.0.2 and pdfHtml is 1.0.0

Comment: Those versions should match and not produce this error. Can you make sure you are using the release versions 7.0.2 and 1.0.0? We added some extra font-functionality in 7.0.3 to support the future release of pdfHTML 1.0.1, running on a development commit for one of the two libraries might be the cause of the mismatch.

Comment: Issue resolved. I changed to latest versions 7.0.3 and 1.0.1. Now its working fine. Thank you Samuel.

Comment: iText `7.0.3` is released, but pdfHTML `1.0.1` is not yet released. Please clarify what *exactly* you did. Are you using `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`?

Comment: Sorry. I had updated iText version to 7.0.3 only. pdfHTML is 1.0.0. Typing mistake.

Comment: pdfHTML 1.0.0 is not compatible with iText 7.0.3, only with 7.0.2. pdfHTML 1.0.1, to be released end July 2017, will be compatible with iText 7.0.4, to be released simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

After updating versions to 7.0.3 and 1.0.0, issue is resolved.

Comment: How is that even possible? pdfHTML 1.0.1 is not released yet, and I am the release engineer at iText Software, so I should know.

Comment: Hi Amedee. My bad. Only iText version I had updated to 7.0.3 pdfHtml is remain same ass 1.0.0

Comment: iText Core `7.0.3` and pdfHTML `1.0.0` are not compatible. See this answer: