# iText7 Html to Pdf Conversion exception

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I get this error when I try to run the line:

```
`HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(htmlSource), pdfDocument, converterProperties);`
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.itextpdf.layout.font.FontSet.getFonts()Ljava/util/Set;    at
>   com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.processDocument(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:107)
>     at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.Attacher.attach(Attacher.java:18)   at
>   com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(HtmlConverter.java:108)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:85)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.lambda.pdfgen.demo.PdfGenerator.parseLocal(PdfGenerator.java:98)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.lambda.pdfgen.demo.PdfGenerator.main(PdfGenerator.java:44)

I have already seen a solution that recommends changing the html2pdf artifact version to 1.0.1 in my pom.xml

```
`<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>`
```

but that version doesn't seem to exist yet. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Please give the link where you saw that solution, because indeed pdfHTML 1.0.1 is not yet released (and I should know, because "release engineer" is one of my many hats at iText Software).

Comment: Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628839/itext-7-html-to-pdf-conversion?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. I commented on that other question. At best they are using `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`, not from Maven Central but from the iText Artifactory.

Comment: Apparently they only updated iText to `7.0.3` and pdfHTML is still at `1.0.0`. Please try again with these versions.

Comment: Made sure the quoted stack trace is shown as a quote

Comment: Thanks Amedee, however I only get the above Exception when I update iText to 7.0.3 and leave pdfHtml at 1.0.0 It worked fine with 7.0.2, but I need to use a feature introduced in 7.0.3.

Comment: Confirmed, pdfHTML is only compatible with iText Core 7.0.2, not with 7.0.3. pdfHTML 1.0.1 will be released end of July 2017, together with iText Core 7.0.4.

Comment: Meanwhile you can already use the `SNAPSHOT` builds from the iText Artifactory server.