# iText 7 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: itext, itext7

I just started developing a new function to convert HTML page to PDF. I use iText 7. Followed the instruction [here](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/converting-html-pdf/pdfhtml-accessible-pdf-creation)!.

And now i get the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.itextpdf.layout.font.FontSet.getFonts()Ljava/util/Set;`

I have created pom.xml following the instruction [here](http://developers.itextpdf.com/itext-7)! but still received the same error.

I use eclipse. I put the pom.xml in the WebContent folder and received the error. Same result when moved the pom.xml into the WEB-INF folder.

Is the directory for the pom.xml wrong?

I've gone through the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791275/itext7-html-to-pdf-conversion-exception)! and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628839/itext-7-html-to-pdf-conversion?rq=1)! but still doesn't work

Please advice.

Comment: Which versions are you using in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: I use version 7.0.3 in pom.xml.. Same version with my jar files. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pdfHTML `1.0.0` is not compatible with iText Core `7.0.3`, it is only compatible with iText Core `7.0.2`. Please refer to the compatibility matrix on GitHub for details: https://github.com/itext/itext7/releases/tag/7.0.3

iText Core `7.0.4` and pdfHTML `1.0.1`, scheduled to be released together later this month, will also be compatible.

Meanwile if you want to use snapshot builds, you can add this to your `pom.xml` and use iText Core `7.0.4-SNAPSHOT` and pdfHTML `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>itext-snapshots</id>
    <name>iText Repository - snapshots</name>
    <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/snapshots</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

**Use at your own risk**, because snapshot builds are unsupported and are only for experienced developers who are willing to contribute to iText by following the latest development and submitting pull requests.

**NEVER USE SNAPSHOT BUILDS IN A PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT**

Or just wait until the end of the month, when you can use iText Core `7.0.4` and pdfHTML `1.0.1`.

Comment: Thanks very much Amedee. I dowloaded iText Core version 7.0.2 and the error is gone. It exported the pdf file as expected. Thanks again.